# How to import the "QGis" class in a script?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2.8

I want to check which type of geometry the current layer has. Therefore I use
the PyQGIS documentation on [Access to Geometry](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html#access-to-geometry) and my code looks like:

```
if iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().wkbType() == QGis.WKBPoint:
    print True
```

If I run this code I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Qgis' is not defined
```

I can't import a `QGis` class because I get an error that it does not exist.
Are there steps missing or how can I use this QGis class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to add `qgis.core` module as the `QGis.WkbType` belongs to it:

```
from qgis.core import *
```

I tested this on a script and it worked for me:

```
##Test=name

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *

layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().wkbType() == QGis.WKBPoint
print layer
```

The script prints a *True/False* statement in the Python Console.

Hope this helps!

---

**Edit**:

From the Python Console, you can type the following to see some help descriptions:

```
>>> help (QGis.WkbType)
Help on class WkbType in module qgis._core:
```

Comment: I noticed that you're using QGIS 2.8, I tested this on 2.6.1 so not completely sure if my post will work for you.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if one only needs to access to a few classes/enums, the recommended way of importing them is, e.g., `from qgis.core import QGis`. When you import everything (i.e., using the asterisk), you are importing lots of classes you don't really need, cluttering your environment. See https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module

Comment: Thank you @Joseph. I didn't know the help funktion ;). But now it works for me. It is a bit strange that I have to import it even in the QGIS Python console...

Comment: @gcarrillo - Thank you, that is a very good tip. One which I also need to do more often (I have a bad habit of being lazy!)

Comment: @Martin - Most welcome buddy! That is indeed strange because in QGIS 2.6.1, there's no need to import that class at all! But glad it's working for you with help from gcarrillo.